# Cypress: Troubleshooting unexpected visit/request errors

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to test a part of oauth flow. Step one is made a POST to our endpoint, then it redirects to another site. Here's what happens:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is because my cypress code has an issue, not my backend code. But regardless: **how do I see everything in the request cypress made so I can troubleshoot this?**

Answer (score 1):

Add `failOnStatusCode: false` option to continue and receive a result, but `cy.visit()` yields the window object which may not be useful.

If you use

```
cy.request({
  url, 
  method: 'POST',
  failOnStatusCode: false,
  ...
```

it will yield the response, see [Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Yields).